# How to handle Uncaught URIError: URI malformed in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, url-encoding

How to handle this error? I have checked for answers, couldn't find any.
Tried $[exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) , but no luck.

Error from browser console:

```
Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at Ad (angular.min.js:113)
    at tc.$$parse (angular.min.js:115)
    at tc.$$parseLinkUrl (angular.min.js:116)
    at Jf.$get (angular.min.js:119)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:44)
    at angular.min.js:45
    at d (angular.min.js:43)
    at e (angular.min.js:43)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:43)
```

Input URL samples (copy the url with '$^%$^')

http://localhost:8080/#!/myroute $^%$^
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach#usage $^%$^

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @31piy , added $exceptionHandler in config, but did not catch any errors there, also tried to wrap my $routeProvider in a try catch block, but no luck.

Comment: It is not possible to provide the solution until we see your code. With my previous comment, I meant to see your code. Where did you use `$exceptionHander`, and above all, which line in your code throws this error?

Comment: Hi, it is not my code that throws error, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach#usage $^%$^

this link will throw error.

I added a temporary fix by editing angular source code and wrapping '$$parseLinkUrl' method with try catch.

error is causing when a % symbol is a part of URL.